# POSTGRES: Select query on a refcursor returned from a function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I have a POSTGRES function that returns a refcursor as output. Printing the refcursor shows an output similar to this:

```
A     B
==========
1    dog
2    cat
3    tiger
```

My question is:

**How can I execute a query on top of this refcursor?
Something like:**

```
select A from (function_returning_refcursor());
```

Comment: [is this relevant?](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-server/9308-select-ref-cursor.html)

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Does that link suggest creating a type separately and return that instead of refcursor? If so, I don't want to do it that way.

Comment: This is exceedingly unclear. What's each refcursor a query over? What do you expect 'A' to be? What output do you expect?

Comment: I have posted the content of the refcursor above. Say the refcursor was populated by an initial query that selected everything from a couple of tables after a union. And the output looks something like the above. Now, I am trying select only a particular column from the above output i.e A. A's values have been shown as integers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another function that consumes a `refcursor` and does whatever you want with the cursor contents. e.g.:

```
select f2(curs) from function_returning_refcursor() curs;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how that function f2 would do the query on the ref cursor? Which is basically what I don't understand and is my question.

Comment: @M10TheMist The PL/PgSQL documentation covers fetching from cursors: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html . Note that you can also `FETCH` the results at the SQL level: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html